# How to delete unnecessary options from Notebook[]?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

By default `Notebook[]` has a small set of `Options`:

```
In[4]:= Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]

Out[4]= {FrontEndVersion -> 
  "7.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (February 18, 2009)", 
 StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb", 
 WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}, 
 WindowSize -> {616, 537}}
```

Sometimes I wish to modify `Notebook` appearance and set additional `Options`. For example I like to have comments to be `Plain` rather than `Bold`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 AutoStyleOptions -> {"CommentStyle" -> {FontWeight -> Plain, 
     FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.6`], ShowAutoStyles -> False, 
     ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, AutoNumberFormatting -> False}}]
```

Now `Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]` will return also new option I have set.

But sometimes I wish to restore default behavior and delete additional `Options`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Igor's answer is almost right. To remove the options set by

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 AutoStyleOptions -> {"CommentStyle" -> {FontWeight -> Plain, 
     FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.6`], ShowAutoStyles -> False, 
     ShowSyntaxStyles -> False, AutoNumberFormatting -> False}}]
```

You need to run

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 AutoStyleOptions -> {"CommentStyle" -> Inherited}]
```

But this only works for options that are standard and have a default to inherit (if it's a cell then from the enclosing section or notebook, if it's a notebook then from the stylesheet). What if you make up your own option, e.g.

```
Protect[HiddenData];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], HiddenData -> {"here's a string"}]
```

I don't know how to programmatically remove this option.

---

### Edit:

Actually, to remove the HiddenData option created above, I can use something like

```
NotebookPut[DeleteCases[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
                        $CellContext`HiddenData -> _], 
            EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

---

### Edit 2:

Mr Wizard asked how to remove all user-set notebook options. Assuming that this means all options that can't be inherited, then I believe that the following should work:

```
NotebookPut[
 With[{nb = NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]], opts = Options[Notebook][[All, 1]]}, 
  Prepend[Select[Rest@nb, MemberQ[opts, First[#]] &], First@nb]], 
 EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

But maybe there are options associated with the StyleSheet that I've ignored...

If he meant how do you get back to your system's default notebook options - then you can just delete all notebook options:

```
NotebookPut[Notebook[First@NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]], 
            EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Comment: Thank you. The method with `NotebookGet`/`NotebookPut` is absolutely new for me.

Comment: How do you use this to delete all user-set Notebook options?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Good question. See Edit 2.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I mean up to differences in formatting that have no real effect. I guess it's a maths phrase. Think of the Mod[] operator used in [Modular_Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). In a physics system, if you have symmetries that change the form of the maths, but not the physics, you can say something is the same "modulo a symmetry transformation".

Answer (score 2):

(1) Select `Format -> Options Inspector` (or `Shift+Ctrl+O` on Windows)

(2) For the two fields next to "Show option values" select `Notebook` and `as text`

(3) Select and delete all text in the box below

(4) Click `Apply`

After understanding NotebookGet, I believe this works for full options reset.

```
NotebookPut[
 Notebook@First@NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]],
 EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Good question!  I'll have to think about that.  I tend to do these things manually, since I don't do them often.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> Inherited]
```

Igor

Comment: That does not seem to work.  That is, the styled comments remain styled.